# rxjava - Combine onerror and timout handling

Tags: asynchronous, rx-java

I will start with what I want to achieve.

- I want to call a method that returns an Observabe.
- I do not know if the called method handles exceptions and timeouts
- I want to combine observables in my call (merge/zip etc)
- if one method fails, I want the answers from the methods that succeeded - 
  I don't want to break the flow.

In case of exception, I am capable of handling it and continuing with the flow, 
but when I try to add timeoutmanagement I fail.

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    createObservables(false, true); // stalls for timeout
    zip();
}
private static void createObservables(final boolean throwException, 
                                      final boolean stall) {

   obs1 = Observable.just(1);

   obs1 = obs1.map(new Func1<Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override public Integer call(Integer integer) {
            int i = 0;
            if (throwException)
                getObj().equals("");
            if (stall)
                zzz(10);
            return ++integer;
        }

   });
   obs2 = Observable.just(111);
}

private static void zip() {
    System.out.println("**Zip**");

    obs1 = obs1.onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, Integer>() {
        @Override public Integer call(Throwable throwable) {
            return 999;
        }
    });

    obs1 = obs1.timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, new Func2<Integer, Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public ArrayList<Integer> call(Integer integer1, Integer integer2) {
            ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            integers.add(integer1);
            integers.add(integer2);
            return integers;
        }
    }).subscribe(new Observer<Object>() {....}
    );
}
```

Now, when I call

```
createObservables(false , false);  // no exceptions and timeouts
```

I get onNext - [2, 111].
then I call

```
createObservables(true, false);  // throw exception in one method only
```

I get onNext - [999, 111] - which is what I want. Exception and the result from the second method.
But when I call

```
createObservables(false, true); // stall on timeout
```

I get only onError.
But I want to get the other method answer.
Thanks.

Comment: `obs1.timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).onErrorReturn` is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an observable for your timeout value, in this case you want the same value as your error case:

```
Observable obs1Timeout = Observable.just(999);
```

Then in your timeout policy give it this observable as the fallback to use in the case of a timeout:

```
obs1 = obs1.timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, obs1Timeout);
```